# Auto Refresh Filter when Changing Dropdown Selection from Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have created a few dropdown menus on one sheet that allows the user to make various selections which influence what data is presented on the second sheet. Depending on the selection made, there can be any given number of blank records.

So on the second sheet I added a filter to remove any blank records. However, this filter does not refresh every time a new selection is made. I tried using the following code in the module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

End Sub
```

However when I go and make a new selection on sheet 1, the filter doesn't refresh. I believe its because I am not manually changing any cell in sheet 2, so the code doesn't pick up on the change in data.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by amending the code as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    Sheets("Sheet 2").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter

End Sub
```

Seems I just had to understand the code I was using :)